# seeking clarification on constexpr function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, constexpr

Consider the following code segment:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A
{
    public:
        //constexpr A (){i = 0;}
        constexpr A ():i(0){}
        void show (void){cout << i << endl; return;}
    private:
        int i;
};

class B
{
    public:
        constexpr B(A a){this->a = a;}
        //constexpr B(A a):a(a){}
        void show (void){a.show(); return;}
    private:
        A a;
};

int main (void)
{

    A a;
    B b(a);
    b.show();

    return (0);
}
```

Inside the definition of `class A`, if the current constructor definition is replaced by the definition commented out:

```
//constexpr A (){i = 0;}
```

the following compilation error ensues (note that line numbers correspond to original code):

```
g++ -ggdb -std=c++17 -Wall -Werror=pedantic -Wextra  -c code.cpp
code.cpp: In constructor ‘constexpr A::A()’:
code.cpp:8:30: error: member ‘A::i’ must be initialized by mem-initializer in ‘constexpr’ constructor
         constexpr A (){i = 0;}
                              ^
code.cpp:12:13: note: declared here
         int i;
             ^
make: *** [makefile:20: code.o] Error 1
```

However, the code compiles perfectly with either definition for the constructor of `class B` (the current as well as the definition commented out in the source code reproduced.)

I have looked at the following pages with the objective of understanding what is going on here:

[constexpr specifier (since C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

[Constant expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression)

I must admit that I am not able to figure out why the member initializer list is mandated in the case of the constructor for A, and not in the case of B.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A` has a default constructor (which is `constexpr` by the way). The relevant requirements for a `constexpr` constructor [that you are citing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) are as follows:

> for the constructor of a class or struct, ... every non-variant
>   non-static data member must be initialized.

The only requirement that it is "initialized". Not "explicitly initialized". A default constructor will meet the initialization requirement. `A` has a default constructor. So your `B`'s `a` class member gets initialized by its default constructor, meeting this requirement, so you don't have to explicitly initialize it in `B`'s constructor's initialization list.

On the other hand, your garden variety `int` does not have a default constructor. For that reason, `A`'s `constexpr` constructor must initialize it explicitly.